# How to change an ImageView inside recyclerView adapter from another class?

Tags: android

How do I change ImageView in charchama_adapter class from RectangularIViewObjSeter?

setView Method inside RectangularIViewObjSeter class is where I write my block of code to change image view inside recycler view adapter. Neither value nor resource is null or 0. I think the problem is setting the context in the image view. But I'm not sure.

```
public class RectangularIViewObjSeter implements IViewObjSeter {
Context context;
ImageView imageView;

public RectangularIViewObjSeter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void setView(String Value, int Resource) {

    imageView = ((Activity)context).findViewById(Resource);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Value);
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageView);
}
}
```

My recycler view is like this(PS it is inside a fragment)

```
public class charchama_adapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<charchama_adapter.MyViewHolder> {


View v;
ArrayList<ContentPOJO> list;
int sizeOfNesContentList;
int Height, Width;
Context context;


public charchama_adapter(ArrayList<ContentPOJO> list, Context context) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.list = list;



    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        sizeOfNesContentList = 0;
    } else {
        sizeOfNesContentList = list.size();
    }


}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    v = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.charchama_adapter, 
null);
    Height = parent.getHeight();
    Width = parent.getWidth();
    context = parent.getContext();
    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SetView setView = new SetView(context);
    ViewResource viewResource = new 
ViewResourceAdapter().setHeaderResource(R.id.contentHeader_adapterCharchama)
            .setBodyResource(R.id.contentBody_adapterCharchama)
            .setImageResource(R.id.backgroundImage_charchamaAdapter)
            .setAuthorAndDateResource(R.id.autherAndDate_charchamaFragment)

.setNewsCategory(R.id.newsCategory_charchamaAdapter).getViewResource();

    ContentPOJO contentPOJO = list.get(position);
    setView.setResources(viewResource, contentPOJO, false);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sizeOfNesContentList;
}
}
```

This is another class to set my view

```
public class SetView implements ISetView {
Context context;


public SetView(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
    public void setResources(ViewResource viewResource, ContentPOJO 
contentPOJO, Boolean CircularImage) {




    if(viewResource.getImageResource() !=0){
        IViewObjSeter iViewObjSeter;
        if (CircularImage == true) {

        iViewObjSeter = new CircularIViewObjSeter(context);

    } else {
        iViewObjSeter = new RectangularIViewObjSeter(context);
    }

      iViewObjSeter.setView(contentPOJO.getImageURL(), 
viewResource.getImageResource());
  }

    TextViewSetter textViewSetter = new TextViewSetter(context);

    if (viewResource.getAuthorAndDateResource() != 0) {
        if (contentPOJO.getDate().equals(null)) {
            textViewSetter.setView(contentPOJO.getAuthor(), 
viewResource.getAuthorAndDateResource());
        } else {
            textViewSetter.setView(contentPOJO.getAuthor() + " | " + 
contentPOJO.getDate(), viewResource.getAuthorAndDateResource());
        }
    }

    if(viewResource.getBodyResource()!=0){
        textViewSetter.setView(contentPOJO.getStory(), 
viewResource.getBodyResource());
    }
    if(viewResource.getHeaderResource() !=0){
        textViewSetter.setView(contentPOJO.getHeading(), 
viewResource.getHeaderResource());
    }
    if(viewResource.getNewsCategory()!=0){
        textViewSetter.setView(contentPOJO.getNewsCategory(), 
viewResource.getNewsCategory());
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `charchama_adapter` class, you define a field named `context` as below:

```
Context context;
```

But you didn't initialize it in **constructor** of `charchama_adapter` class, this is the issue.

```
public charchama_adapter(ArrayList<ContentPOJO> list, Context context) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context; //add this line


    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        sizeOfNesContentList = 0;
    } else {
        sizeOfNesContentList = list.size();
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work. However for context, i did  context = parent.getContext(); in onBindViewHolder method of charchama_adapter class. Why i didn't context in the constructor is because i will have to change initializing new charchama_adapter in a lot of places and i might need this context later on.

Comment: I think the error is in the typecasting of ImageView in  RectangularIViewObjSeter class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have an answer to my question. LOL
Insted of ((Activity)context).findViewById(), view.findViewById() seemed to work well.

```
public class RectangularIViewObjSeter implements IViewObjSeter {
Context context;
ImageView imageView;

public RectangularIViewObjSeter(Context context) {
this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void setView(View view, String Value, int Resource) {

imageView = view.findViewById(Resource);
 Picasso.get().load(Value).into(imageView);
}
}
```